Unable to connect to MySQL database: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306
I running docker compose but for some reason i cant figure out, the node_server container cannot run, it keep exiting due the above error.
Here is my docker compose files
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: optimal_mysql_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./optimalbackend/.env
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=optimalhand
    networks:
      - optimal_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  back-end:
    image: optimalhandyman-backend:v1.1
    container_name: optimal_node_server
    env_file:
      - ./optimalbackend/.env
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DB_HOST=localhost
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_NAME=optimalhand
    networks:
      - optimal_network
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  front-end:
    image: teddtycoon/optimalhandyman-website:v1.0
    container_name: optimal_react_frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_URL=http://back-end:5000
    depends_on:
      - back-end

networks:
  optimal_network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db:


Here is my server.js
let express = require("express");


let dbConnect = require("./dbConnect");
dbConnect.connectMysql()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());

//Set Router
const reviewRouters = require("./routes/reviewsRoute");
app.use("/api/reviews", reviewRouters)


//Check connection
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening at port", port);
});


Then here is the sequelize connection
"use strict"

require("dotenv").config();
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const mysql = require("mysql2")

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: 3306, // MySQL container's internal port
      dialect: 'mysql'
    }
  );
  // Testing the connection
  const connectMysql = async () => {
    try {
      await sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log(`Successful connection to MySQL Database
  ${process.env.DB_NAME}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Unable to connect to MySQL database:", error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };
  module.exports = {
    Sequelize: sequelize,
  connectMysql
};

Then my my .env file
DB_NAME=optimalhand
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=optimal_mysql_db
DB_PORT=3306

I have confirmed that the root in mysql workbench is running on localhost:3306
I have turned off firewall.
I have played around the host names and even entering the environment variable directly instead of pulling from .env file to no avail.
I have referred to a similar problem that was solved here but the approach did not work for me.
Here is the whole error message
Unable to connect to MySQL database: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306
optimal_node_server     |     at ConnectionManager.connect (/optimalbackend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)
optimal_node_server     |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
optimal_node_server     |     at async ConnectionManager._connect (/optimalbackend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
optimal_node_server     |     at async /optimalbackend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32 {
optimal_node_server     |   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306
optimal_node_server     |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1606:16) {
optimal_node_server     |     errno: -111,
optimal_node_server     |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
optimal_node_server     |     syscall: 'connect',
optimal_node_server     |     address: '172.20.0.2',
optimal_node_server     |     port: 3306,
optimal_node_server     |     fatal: true
optimal_node_server     |   },

